# Ожидания выполнения кода

Tags: xcode, swift4, mapkit

Есть у меня функция для проверки корректности написания города, если названия города корректное я записываю его данные в объект класса MarkerData.

```
func searchCity(city : String, marker : MarkerData) {
    let searchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = city
    let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
    activeSearch.start { (response , error) in
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        if response != nil
        {
            let latitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
            let longitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude
            let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
            marker.setTitle(value: "----")
            marker.setName(value: city)
            marker.setCoordinate(value: coordinate)
            marker.setAlive(value: true)
        }
        else {
            marker.setAlive(value: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Проверяет все хорошо, но когда делается запрос на проверку для ответ нужно некоторое время, но код не ждет ответа и идет далее. Мне критически важно чтобы код не шел далее пока не будет получен ответ. Какие есть решения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно, [start()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch/1452652-start) это асинхронная функция с *completion handler*, он выполняется когда поиск заканчивается. Во первых в документации написано что вы должны вызывать ее только один раз, то есть если один поиск запущен, запуск второй раз вызовет не предсказуемое поведение или крэш. Я бы вывел *activeSearch* в переменную класса, и вызывал бы [cancel()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch/1452160-cancel) если предыдущий поиск еще не закончился (это QA case вообще то, но лучше сразу об этом подумать).

Теперь по сути вопроса: поместите вызов функции продолжения выполнения в *completion handler*, так у и будет синхронный вызов после поиска.
Не забудьте обезопасится от memory leak, перед *(response , error)* добавьте *[weak self]*, и потом вызовите *self?.continueMyProgramExecution(city, coordinate)*.